# Spark Hang with output status: ACCEPTED in YARN MODE

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

My Spark environment

```
Spark  -> 2.1.0
Hadoop -> 2.8.1
Eclipse -> Neon 2
```

I stuck while getting the spark context in yarn mode.How I can get spark context in yarn mode,Please help me to resolve.

My Hadoop,Yarn and Spark  installation is successful.

```
$ jps
3200 NameNode
5264 ExecutorLauncher
5328 CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend
3555 SecondaryNameNode
5316 CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend
7590 Jps
3357 DataNode
4045 NodeManager
5118 SparkSubmit
3727 ResourceManager
```

My source code to get spark context in yarn mode :-

```
public class JavaClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest").setMaster("yarn-client");
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();


        System.out.println(spark.version() + " : " + spark.sparkContext());

    }
}
```

Output :-

```
17/09/22 10:24:11 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506052073594_0011 (state: ACCEPTED)

17/09/22 10:24:12 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506052073594_0011 (state: ACCEPTED) 

17/09/22 10:24:13 INFO Client: Application report for application_1506052073594_0011 (state: ACCEPTED)

.
.
.
```

and so on , not returning spark session.

Comment: I experienced the same using intellij...

Comment: Do you see any warnings in Resource Manager log file?

Answer (score 2):

Check in Resource Manager UI (localhost:8088) that you have available memory/cpu slots for Application Master and executors

Answer (score 0):

Try just "yarn" instead of "yarn-client"

public class JavaClient {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest").setMaster("yarn");
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();


    System.out.println(spark.version() + " : " + spark.sparkContext());

}
```